# What if in DPR (dense passage retrieval), the answer belongs to more than one passage?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, transformer, large-language-models

In the [DPR paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.04906.pdf)
the dataset is expected to be in this format D = {<q<sub>i</sub>, p<sub>i</sub><sup>+</sup>, p<sub>i,1</sub><sup>-</sup>, ... >}

With only one positive passage, but it is possible that the question requires an answer that spans knowledge from more than one positive passage.

Another issue is that, if we consider other positive answers from the batch as negative, (the Gold strategy in the paper) it is possible that those other positive passages are relevant for the question into consideration.

How should the DPR model be trained in such a case?